# Importing a specific git commit hash in Gradle (Kotlin DSL)

Tags: gradle

I want to import commit a961b19 of this [project](https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api/) as a source dependency in a Kotlin project which uses Gradle.

I added this into the settings.gradle.kts of my project

```
sourceControl {
    gitRepository(java.net.URI.create("https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api.git#a961b19")) {
        producesModule("com.github.v3rtumnus:yahoofinance-api")
    }
}
```

and using this dependency in my build.gradle.kts file:

```
implementation("com.github.v3rtumnus:yahoofinance-api:1.0.0")
```

I am trying to build the commit `a961b19` to use with my project. However, I am lost as to where I might specify the git commit to use. When I try to build it this way, I get the following exception:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not list available versions for Git repository at https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api.git#a961b19.
Could not run ls-remote for https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api.git#a961b19
https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api.git#a961b19: Redirection blocked: redirect https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api.git#a961b19/ -> https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api not allowed
https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api.git#a961b19: Redirection blocked: redirect https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api.git#a961b19/ -> https://github.com/v3rtumnus/yahoofinance-api not allowed
```

Is there a way to build a specific commit in `build.gradle.kts`